# Is there any significance to the dances that the girls perform in "Satan in Goray"?

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, satan-in-goray

Before Reb Itche Mates and Rechele's wedding, we have this scene, after the description of the "jester" for the wedding:

> The girls nudged one another and giggled. They performed first the Mad Dance and then the Scissors Dance and the Water Dance, lifting their dresses as though to cross a puddle. Like strangers they averted their eyes. It was some time before they agreed to accept the pieces of honey cake which were their due; they tasted only a single berry of the jam set before them.
> <sub>*Satan in Goray*, part 2, chapter 1: "The Wedding" (translated by Jacob Sloan)</sub>

The "Mad Dance" looks to me to be commentary on Rechele's fragile sanity; she's known to be not the most stable person in town. Is there any significance to the other dances that the girls perform? (Or another interpretation of the Mad Dance?)

Comment: Aside from any specific literary intent, these are known dances that help build setting, although they might be slightly anachronistic in the 17th century of the novel:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sher_(dance)